# Howto submit JSF ajax field during form submit

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem with a JSF 2 form that contains an ajax field. When I use the mouse to press the submit button of the form while the cursor is still in the ajaxified input field the input value of the field does not get submitted before the action is triggered in the backing bean. Also the attached validator and converter are not triggered.

```
<h:form id="invoice">
    ...
    <h:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.amount}" required="true" validator="#{invoiceBean.validateAmount}">
        <f:converter converterId="CurrencyConverter" />
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="@this"/>
    </h:inputText>  
    <h:commandButton action="#{invoiceBean.processInvoice()}" />
</h:form>
```

I also tried to enhance the command button with `<f:ajax />` but the result stayed the same. Other (non-ajax) fields on the same form (not shown in the code snippet above) are submitted correctly. The ajax field is also submitted, converted and validated if I click somwhere else on the page before submitting but not when using the button directly.

Is there anything I am missing to have the field also be submitted on/before form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [`<h:inputText>`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_inputText.html) ajax behaviour: use [`<f:ajax>`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html) with the default event **valueChange**, which is the default event for all input components. This is indeed equivalent to omitting the `event` attribute:

```
<f:ajax render="@this" />
```

Regarding the [`<h:commmandButton>`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_commandButton.html) component, don't forget to specify the `execute` attribute of `<f:ajax>`:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" />
```

otherwise it will default to `@this`, therefore rendering vane your effort.

Comment: Thanks for the input :) I removed `event="blur"`. But still no matter if the button has `<f:ajax execute="@form" />` or not the fields value is not submitted.

Comment: In this case you may suffer of a conversion or validation problem. Put some logging in there. And for ensuring that the field is submitted, check the HTTP traffic with firebug. Also add `<h:message>` component and update it with ajax

Comment: @Downvoter : what's disturbing you exactly in my answer?